# Textboxes validate by Dropdownlist

Tags: vb.net

VB aspx.net

I have a few textboxes and a dropdownlist. Value input by user in the textbox will look something like this (00000000000000015010000000000). mid(16,4) will be the date (yymm) that i need to cross check with the dropdownlist.

For example the user select 1 year in the dropdownlist application take today date subtraction the value input by user if its more than the dropdownlist selected value warn the user that the value input is wrong.

Comment: Please write description and arrange code

Comment: What's this? i don't understand anything.

Comment: Suggestion: use `DateTimePicker` for dates to make it easier for date differences. Like: `Dim d as Date = DateTimePicker1.Value`. check for 1 year expiry: `if d <= d.AddYears(1) Then ' Do Something`

Comment: I don't see a question here, just a run-on sentence

Comment: Please read [ask] and take the [tour].  You are just wasting everyone's time with something so unclear and vague as this.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want to pop an error message if the year/date selected is more than one year in the future?

- First thing, use a `DateTimePicker` control, *NOT* a `TextBox`

Then, you'll want to compare the value of this `DateTimePicker`, and put it into an `If statement`

```
Dim dateToCheck As Date = DateTimePicker1.Value

If dateToCheck > Date.Today.AddYears(1) Then
   MessageBox.Show("This is not a valid date.", "Error")
   Exit Sub
End If
```

Alternatively, you can validate the `DateTimePicker` control to not allow dates over/before a certain date.

```
DateTimePicker1.MaxDate = Today.AddYears(1)
DateTimePicker1.MinDate = Today
```